# Bouncing ball: number of bounces and tracelled distance

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I have received an interesting javascript practice exercise that I'm trying to understand. The problem below (screenshot) needs to be solved with a while loop.

> The *coefficient of restitution* of a ball, a number between 0 and 1, specifies how much energy is conserved when a ball hits a rigid surface. A coefficient of .9, for instance, means a bouncing ball will rise to 90% of its previous height after each bounce.
>
> Write a program to input a coefficient of restitution and an initial hight in meters, and report how many times a ball bounces when dropped from its initial height before it rises to a height of less than 10 centimeters.  Also report the total distance traveled by the ball before this point.
>
> The coefficients of restitution for a tennis ball, basketball, super ball, and softball are .7, .75, .9, and .3, respectively.

I'm trying to use the code below to complete this, but it simply hangs.

```
 function code1() {
  var heightM = getInputOne();
  var heightCm = heightM * 100;
  var coefficient = getInputTwo();
  var distance = getInputOne();
  var bounce = 0;

  while (heightCm >= 10) {
    bounce = bounce + 1;
    distance = distance + (heightM * coefficient * 2);
    heightCm = heightCm * coefficient;
  }
  console.log(bounce);
  console.log(distance);

}
```

Here are the functions being called within it

```
// Return the text in the 'In 1:' box
function getInputOne() {
  var input = getElement("inOne");
  return input.value;
}

// Return the text in the 'In 2:' box
function getInputTwo() {
  var input = getElement("inTwo");
  return input.value;
}
```

Any help with this would be appreciated. Also, let me know what other data might be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues:

- The value read from the `input.value` property is a string, not a number. This effects how the `+` operator works in the following expression:

  ```
  distance = distance + (heightM * coefficient * 2);
  ```

  As `distance` is a string, the `+` is a concatenation, not an addition. And so `distance` will just be growing string of digits.
- although you adapt `heightCm` in every iteration, you don't do the same with `heightM`. It maintains its original value, and so the distance calculation is wrong.
- You should check that the input value for `coefficient` is within the limits. If you allow a value of 1 or more, then the calculated height will increase in every iteration of the loop, which will make it hang.

So I would suggest this code:

```js
function getBounces(heightM, coefficient) {
  var distance = heightM; // avoid reading input twice
  var bounce = 0;

  while (heightM >= 0.10) { // just compare with meters...
    bounce = bounce + 1;
    heightM = heightM * coefficient;
    distance = distance + heightM * 2;
    if (bounce > 100) throw "error";
  }
  return [bounce, distance];
}

document.getElementById('calc').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var heightM = getInputOne();
  var coefficient = getInputTwo();
  if (coefficient >= 1 || coefficient < 0) {
    alert('invalid input for coefficient');
    return;
  }
  var result = getBounces(heightM, coefficient);
  outputResults(result[0], result[1]);
});


// Return the text in the 'In 1:' box
function getInputOne() {
  var input = document.getElementById("inOne");
  return +input.value; // add the + for conversion to number
}

// Return the text in the 'In 2:' box
function getInputTwo() {
  var input = document.getElementById("inTwo");
  return +input.value; // add the + for conversion to number
}

function outputResults(bounce, distance) {
  var output = document.getElementById("bounce");
  output.textContent = bounce;
  output = document.getElementById("dist");
  output.textContent = distance.toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
Height: <input id="inOne">m<br>
Coefficient: <input id="inTwo"> (0 ... 0.99)<br>
<button id="calc">Calculate</button>
<br>
Bounces: <span id="bounce"></span><br>
Distance: <span id="dist"></span>m<br>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped. I think the main issue hanging things up was the string vs. int issue. Additionally, I replaced heightM and heightCM with just height. Lastly, the input error checking is a good idea, I would typically add something like that once I had my core functionality down.